# Validation failed: Park must exist, User must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a project where Users can see dog **Parks** and make individual **Playdates** for each park. The issue I'm having is that the PlaydatesController create action is not persisting the user_id and park_id that each new playdate is associated with. I've tried adding **optional: true** to my Playdate model, which does save each playdate. However, doing this makes a *null* column entry for the user_id and park_id.

All I need is the user_id and park_id to create a playdate and keep the association between playdates and parks... Did I mess up my associations? Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Here's my code:

Playdate MODEL:

```
class Playdate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park
  belongs_to :user

  validates :date, presence: true 
  validates :time, presence: true
end
```

Park MODEL:

```
class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :playdates
  has_many :comments
  has_many :users, through: :comments 
end
```

User MODEL:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parks
  has_many :playdates 
  has_many :comments, through: :parks
end
```

Playdates CONTROLLER:

```
def create
    @playdate = Playdate.new(playdate_params)
    if @playdate.save!
        redirect_to park_path(@park)
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def playdate_params
    params.require(:playdate).permit(:time, :date, :user_id, :park_id)
end
```

Playdates NEW VIEW:

```
<%= form_for @playdate do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.date_field :date %><br><br>
  <%= f.label :time %>
  <%= f.time_field :time %><br><br>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :park_id, @park%>
  <%= f.submit "Add Playdate!" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```ruby
f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
f.hidden_field :park_id, value: @park.id
```

The rendered HTML is not the same between "hidden_field_tag" and "hidden_field". Try by yourself to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Wow, I feel dumb for looking over that. lol Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I spent literally several HOURS on this yesterday!!!!

Comment: We've all been through this ^^'

Comment: I'm still learning, that's for sure. I'm realizing more often than not that the mistakes I make are very simple ones, like this. I need to remember to start debugging with on a "simple" level first, and then work towards higher level debugging techniques (not the other direction...). Thanks again!